# How to install software when you don't have package manager

Tags: linux, debian

I have a docker container running where I want to install a package. Container is bebian based without Package Managers.

The output of `cat /proc/version`

```
Linux version 4.19.0-0.bpo.6-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2~bpo9+1 (2019-11-12)
```

The output of `compgen -c` as from https://superuser.com/questions/726986/installing-software-without-package-manager

```
if
then
else
elif
fi
case
esac
for
select
while
until
do
done
in
function
time
{
}
!
[[
]]
coproc
.
:
[
alias
bg
bind
break
builtin
caller
cd
command
compgen
complete
compopt
continue
declare
dirs
disown
echo
enable
eval
exec
exit
export
false
fc
fg
getopts
hash
help
history
jobs
kill
let
local
logout
mapfile
popd
printf
pushd
pwd
read
readarray
readonly
return
set
shift
shopt
source
suspend
test
times
trap
true
type
typeset
ulimit
umask
unalias
unset
wait
ganesha.nfsd
clock
pam_console_apply
update-alternatives
cracklib-unpacker
sln
pwunconv
cracklib-packer
fsck
capsh
nologin
rtcwake
blockdev
fsfreeze
pam_timestamp_check
newusers
g13-syshelp
alternatives
swapon
zdump
pwck
build-locale-archive
mkfs
applygnupgdefaults
blkid
zic
chpasswd
chroot
mkfs.minix
grpconv
resizepart
addgnupghome
grpunconv
unix_update
addpart
faillock
getcap
usermod
switch_root
userdel
useradd
sfdisk
saslpasswd2
groupadd
cfdisk
vigr
getpcaps
iconvconfig
findfs
hwclock
delpart
blkdiscard
pwhistory_helper
swaplabel
runuser
swapoff
rfkill
groupmod
unix_chkpwd
agetty
wipefs
fdisk
fsck.cramfs
cracklib-check
fsck.minix
sasldblistusers2
fstrim
blkzone
pwconv
vipw
setcap
adduser
ldattach
create-cracklib-dict
chgpasswd
chcpu
fdformat
mkfs.cramfs
losetup
partx
cracklib-format
grpck
ctrlaltdel
mkhomedir_helper
readprofile
sulogin
ldconfig
mkswap
groupmems
pivot_root
groupdel
zramctl
edquota
weak-modules
blkdeactivate
xfs_fsr
fsck.xfs
halt
clddb-tool
reboot
xfs_freeze
showmount
mount.nfs4
lsmod
mount.nfs
blkmapd
xfs_ncheck
xqmstats
convertquota
sm-notify
rpc.idmapd
modprobe
xfs_quota
xfs_spaceman
dmfilemapd
quot
quotaoff
rpc.gssd
rpc.mountd
setquota
rmmod
poweroff
depmod
nfsidmap
xfs_estimate
xfs_repair
nfsiostat
xfs_info
rpc.nfsd
quotacheck
rpc.statd
start-statd
xfs_mdrestore
nfsref
modinfo
runlevel
xfs_metadump
insmod
umount.nfs
rpcbind
xfs_bmap
xfs_logprint
telinit
resolvconf
nfsconf
xfs_rtcp
mkfs.xfs
umount.nfs4
gssproxy
xfs_admin
xfs_mkfile
nfsdcltrack
dmsetup
quotaon
rpcdebug
nfsstat
request-key
nfsconvert
nfsdcld
init
exportfs
xfs_copy
mountstats
xfs_io
rpcinfo
xfs_growfs
shutdown
xfs_db
key.dns_resolver
quotastats
repquota
dmstats
utmpdump
infotocap
db_printlog
lastlog
znew
db_verify
sleep
ls
gpg2
expr
choom
db_stat
gawk
fallocate
sha384sum
cp
db_deadlock
numfmt
printenv
setterm
raw
lastb
setsid
mktemp
base32
gpg-wks-server
fc
tr
db_load
trust
update-crypto-policies
whoami
shred
su
glib-compile-schemas
fmt
dmesg
csplit
sg
dirmngr
chgrp
rename
getent
bashbug
db_dump
mesg
zmore
unexpand
iconv
seq
id
rpm
lsipc
microdnf
nl
cat
pwmake
eject
readlink
ca-legacy
stdbuf
zfgrep
flock
uuidgen
cut
lslocks
zcat
lscpu
who
hash
dd
expand
unshare
logname
db_dump185
brotli
rev
db_replicate
users
mount
gpg-connect-agent
gpg-agent
sh
rpm2cpio
db_recover
zegrep
groups
b2sum
column
mkfifo
fips-finish-install
gpgsplit
colcrt
captoinfo
head
infocmp
colrm
cal
env
findmnt
pathchk
od
linux32
sync
gpgme-json
test
comm
sum
fgrep
xmlwf
stty
gsettings
gpg
tty
db_hotbackup
lsmem
runcon
lslogins
db_log_verify
dir
xmllint
pwscore
gpg-error
egrep
gpgv
tset
tic
zcmp
xmlcatalog
cd
gapplication
ionice
sort
grep
command
getopt
prlimit
gpgv2
fips-mode-setup
ptx
newuidmap
install
basenc
realpath
tabs
basename
watchgnupg
curl
shuf
unalias
gpgconf
db_upgrade
stat
isosize
mv
g13
x86_64
tsort
touch
sprof
gencat
newgrp
paste
tac
gdbus
gpgparsemail
mknod
rmdir
mcookie
date
kill
timeout
getconf
whereis
rm
echo
logger
setpriv
taskset
dircolors
wc
link
uname
reset
sha224sum
ldd
ipcs
tzselect
nice
p11-kit
chcon
fincore
db_checkpoint
dirname
zforce
zdiff
fg
locale
alias
tail
uname26
dirmngr-client
tput
sha1sum
nsenter
rpmverify
gunzip
umask
update-ca-trust
du
base64
lsns
rpmdb
printf
gpasswd
chrt
setarch
arch
write
db_tuner
read
join
pldd
awk
zgrep
gzip
pwd
sed
true
wait
namei
chown
newgidmap
sha256sum
bg
clear
last
hostid
col
look
fold
scriptreplay
wdctl
ln
i386
linux64
gio-querymodules-64
ulimit
db_archive
chmem
hexdump
chage
nohup
type
tee
yes
zless
login
gzexe
sha512sum
false
mkdir
gio-launch-desktop
chmod
more
vdir
bash
modulemd-validator-v1
rpm2archive
lsblk
gpg-zip
mountpoint
sotruss
localedef
toe
wall
getopts
factor
md5sum
catchsegv
rpmquery
nproc
ul
jobs
split
umount
ipcrm
rpmkeys
uniq
cksum
ipcmk
unlink
pr
renice
truncate
script
bashbug-64
[
makedb
df
gio
uuidparse
dbus-run-session
python3
hostnamectl
dbus-monitor
pip3.7
systemd-tty-ask-password-agent
systemd-detect-virt
systemd-sysusers
cmp
systemd-resolve
diff3
busctl
jemalloc.sh
journalctl
debuginfod-find
dbus-daemon
chacl
pip-3.7
portablectl
systemd-ask-password
pip3
pyvenv-3.7
systemd-cgtop
loginctl
nisdomainname
pydoc3
dnsdomainname
pyvenv
dbus-test-tool
systemd-machine-id-setup
dbus-broker
dbus-update-activation-environment
systemd-id128
easy_install-3.7
systemd-tmpfiles
domainname
dbus-send
systemd-mount
systemd-cgls
setfacl
keyctl
pydoc3.7
diff
systemd-firstboot
dbus-launch
systemd-path
dbus-uuidgen
python3.7m
systemd-run
rpcbind
dbus-broker-launch
systemd-analyze
quota
systemd-inhibit
kmod
hostname
timedatectl
pip-3
systemd-stdio-bridge
quotasync
rpcinfo
ypdomainname
python3.7
getfacl
systemd-umount
dbus-cleanup-sockets
systemd-escape
localectl
systemctl
systemd-cat
coredumpctl
sdiff
networkctl
resolvectl
systemd-notify
systemd-delta
systemd-socket-activate
clock
pam_console_apply
update-alternatives
cracklib-unpacker
sln
pwunconv
cracklib-packer
fsck
capsh
nologin
rtcwake
blockdev
fsfreeze
pam_timestamp_check
newusers
g13-syshelp
alternatives
swapon
zdump
pwck
build-locale-archive
mkfs
applygnupgdefaults
blkid
zic
chpasswd
chroot
mkfs.minix
grpconv
resizepart
addgnupghome
grpunconv
unix_update
addpart
faillock
getcap
usermod
switch_root
userdel
useradd
sfdisk
saslpasswd2
groupadd
cfdisk
vigr
getpcaps
iconvconfig
findfs
hwclock
delpart
blkdiscard
pwhistory_helper
swaplabel
runuser
swapoff
rfkill
groupmod
unix_chkpwd
agetty
wipefs
fdisk
fsck.cramfs
cracklib-check
fsck.minix
sasldblistusers2
fstrim
blkzone
pwconv
vipw
setcap
adduser
ldattach
create-cracklib-dict
chgpasswd
chcpu
fdformat
mkfs.cramfs
losetup
partx
cracklib-format
grpck
ctrlaltdel
mkhomedir_helper
readprofile
sulogin
ldconfig
mkswap
groupmems
pivot_root
groupdel
zramctl
edquota
weak-modules
blkdeactivate
xfs_fsr
fsck.xfs
halt
clddb-tool
reboot
xfs_freeze
showmount
mount.nfs4
lsmod
mount.nfs
blkmapd
xfs_ncheck
xqmstats
convertquota
sm-notify
rpc.idmapd
modprobe
xfs_quota
xfs_spaceman
dmfilemapd
quot
quotaoff
rpc.gssd
rpc.mountd
setquota
rmmod
poweroff
depmod
nfsidmap
xfs_estimate
xfs_repair
nfsiostat
xfs_info
rpc.nfsd
quotacheck
rpc.statd
start-statd
xfs_mdrestore
nfsref
modinfo
runlevel
xfs_metadump
insmod
umount.nfs
rpcbind
xfs_bmap
xfs_logprint
telinit
resolvconf
nfsconf
xfs_rtcp
mkfs.xfs
umount.nfs4
gssproxy
xfs_admin
xfs_mkfile
nfsdcltrack
dmsetup
quotaon
rpcdebug
nfsstat
request-key
nfsconvert
nfsdcld
init
exportfs
xfs_copy
mountstats
xfs_io
rpcinfo
xfs_growfs
shutdown
xfs_db
key.dns_resolver
quotastats
repquota
dmstats
utmpdump
infotocap
db_printlog
lastlog
znew
db_verify
sleep
ls
gpg2
expr
choom
db_stat
gawk
fallocate
sha384sum
cp
db_deadlock
numfmt
printenv
setterm
raw
lastb
setsid
mktemp
base32
gpg-wks-server
fc
tr
db_load
trust
update-crypto-policies
whoami
shred
su
glib-compile-schemas
fmt
dmesg
csplit
sg
dirmngr
chgrp
rename
getent
bashbug
db_dump
mesg
zmore
unexpand
iconv
seq
id
rpm
lsipc
microdnf
nl
cat
pwmake
eject
readlink
ca-legacy
stdbuf
zfgrep
flock
uuidgen
cut
lslocks
zcat
lscpu
who
hash
dd
expand
unshare
logname
db_dump185
brotli
rev
db_replicate
users
mount
gpg-connect-agent
gpg-agent
sh
rpm2cpio
db_recover
zegrep
groups
b2sum
column
mkfifo
fips-finish-install
gpgsplit
colcrt
captoinfo
head
infocmp
colrm
cal
env
findmnt
pathchk
od
linux32
sync
gpgme-json
test
comm
sum
fgrep
xmlwf
stty
gsettings
gpg
tty
db_hotbackup
lsmem
runcon
lslogins
db_log_verify
dir
xmllint
pwscore
gpg-error
egrep
gpgv
tset
tic
zcmp
xmlcatalog
cd
gapplication
ionice
sort
grep
command
getopt
prlimit
gpgv2
fips-mode-setup
ptx
newuidmap
install
basenc
realpath
tabs
basename
watchgnupg
curl
shuf
unalias
gpgconf
db_upgrade
stat
isosize
mv
g13
x86_64
tsort
touch
sprof
gencat
newgrp
paste
tac
gdbus
gpgparsemail
mknod
rmdir
mcookie
date
kill
timeout
getconf
whereis
rm
echo
logger
setpriv
taskset
dircolors
wc
link
uname
reset
sha224sum
ldd
ipcs
tzselect
nice
p11-kit
chcon
fincore
db_checkpoint
dirname
zforce
zdiff
fg
locale
alias
tail
uname26
dirmngr-client
tput
sha1sum
nsenter
rpmverify
gunzip
umask
update-ca-trust
du
base64
lsns
rpmdb
printf
gpasswd
chrt
setarch
arch
write
db_tuner
read
join
pldd
awk
zgrep
gzip
pwd
sed
true
wait
namei
chown
newgidmap
sha256sum
bg
clear
last
hostid
col
look
fold
scriptreplay
wdctl
ln
i386
linux64
gio-querymodules-64
ulimit
db_archive
chmem
hexdump
chage
nohup
type
tee
yes
zless
login
gzexe
sha512sum
false
mkdir
gio-launch-desktop
chmod
more
vdir
bash
modulemd-validator-v1
rpm2archive
lsblk
gpg-zip
mountpoint
sotruss
localedef
toe
wall
getopts
factor
md5sum
catchsegv
rpmquery
nproc
ul
jobs
split
umount
ipcrm
rpmkeys
uniq
cksum
ipcmk
unlink
pr
renice
truncate
script
bashbug-64
[
makedb
df
gio
uuidparse
dbus-run-session
python3
hostnamectl
dbus-monitor
pip3.7
systemd-tty-ask-password-agent
systemd-detect-virt
systemd-sysusers
cmp
systemd-resolve
diff3
busctl
jemalloc.sh
journalctl
debuginfod-find
dbus-daemon
chacl
pip-3.7
portablectl
systemd-ask-password
pip3
pyvenv-3.7
systemd-cgtop
loginctl
nisdomainname
pydoc3
dnsdomainname
pyvenv
dbus-test-tool
systemd-machine-id-setup
dbus-broker
dbus-update-activation-environment
systemd-id128
easy_install-3.7
systemd-tmpfiles
domainname
dbus-send
systemd-mount
systemd-cgls
setfacl
keyctl
pydoc3.7
diff
systemd-firstboot
dbus-launch
systemd-path
dbus-uuidgen
python3.7m
systemd-run
rpcbind
dbus-broker-launch
systemd-analyze
quota
systemd-inhibit
kmod
hostname
timedatectl
pip-3
systemd-stdio-bridge
quotasync
rpcinfo
ypdomainname
python3.7
getfacl
systemd-umount
dbus-cleanup-sockets
systemd-escape
localectl
systemctl
systemd-cat
coredumpctl
sdiff
networkctl
resolvectl
systemd-notify
systemd-delta
systemd-socket-activate
```

I need to execute tar command but it is not available. Is it possible to install if no package manager is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little search through above list found that I have `microdnf`. Which helped in installing other package managers. after installing a package manager installed `tar`.